# Is "mutually exclusively" the correct adverb form of "mutually exclusive"?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

In the term "mutually exclusive", I assume the word "mutually" is an adverb for the auxiliary verb "to be", but the whole term acts as an adjective. If I want to use the whole term as an adverb, can I say "mutually exclusively"?

Example: "The two software packages can only be installed mutually exclusive[ly]."

Comment: Why do you think not?

Comment: I am unsure because it sounds wrong or at least strange to have two adverbs in a row like that, especially when one of the adverbs was already part of the expression before making the whole term an adverb.

Comment: @Raimund Krämer Probably both here. More common premodifying  _ly_-forms and central adverbs sound fine (that's probably not worth saying)  ('fairly recently', 'extremely slowly'); 'fairly controversially' and 'infuriatingly slowly' aren't too bad, but 'infuriatingly pedantically' sounds in need of a rephrase. // 'Mutually exclusively' obeys the grammatical rules but in my opinion breaks the rule of idiomaticity. "The two software packages cannot both be installed on the same operating system."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*Mutual exclusion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) and its far more frequent adjectival derivative *mutually exclusive* first appear before the turn of the 19th to the 20th century in scientific, mathematical, and philosophical contexts. Later in the century, [psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusivity_(psychology)), then [computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusivity), adapted the older concept for their own technical use.

Beginning a steep increase after World War II, the adjective hit a plateau in the late 1970s, suggesting not merely an expansion into other academic fields, but also some level of popular usage. The adverb, however, is quite infrequent, as this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mutually+exclusive,mutually+exclusively&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmutually%20exclusive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmutually%20exclusively%3B%2Cc0t1;,mutually%20exclusive;,c0;.t1;,mutually%20exclusively;,c0) shows:

[image]
Quite a number of current uses of the adverb occur in genetic research:

> Although cancer genes with co-occurring and mutually exclusive mutations have already been studied on different scales, there is no timely updated interaction network available for co-mutated and [*mutually exclusively*](https://www.bioportfolio.com/resources/pmarticle/1922861/CM-viewer-visualizing-interaction-network-of-co-mutated-and-mutually-exclusively-mutated.html) mutated cancer genes.

This sentence illustrates how for those writers for whom mutual exclusion is a single concept, the adverb naturally arises when grammar requires. In the hands of a less skilled writer, however, the adverb seems clumsy and jargoned:

> PfEMP1 is encoded by var genes and each var gene is [*mutually exclusively*](http://alexrowe.bio.ed.ac.uk/people/dr-hussein-abkallo/) expressed and encodes a unique PfEMP1 protein.

For some academic writers — and an unfortunate number of popular ones — the adjective and adverb are confused:

> For with Kant the distinction of theoretical from practical reason led to a complete and [*mutually exclusively*](https://books.google.de/books?id=uQlRAQAAMAAJ&q=%22mutually+exclusively%22&dq=%22mutually+exclusively%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_hLLJu9XaAhWI_KQKHfj1DmsQ6AEINTAE) antithesis between the two.

*Antithesis* already has a strong meaning: a partial antithesis wouldn’t be much of one, especially if it could not exclude its opposite, but most of all, it’s a noun, so an adverb is simply incorrect. Other writers fall into the same trap:

> The result will not be the same for [*mutually exclusively*](https://quizlet.com/45649645/finance-investment-rules-flash-cards/) projects if the sizes of the projects are considerably different or the timing of the cash flows are significantly different.
>
> Comfort and class are no longer [*mutually exclusively*](https://www.roomstogo.com/product/Living-Room-Sets/Sofia-Vergara-Catalina-Ruby-7-Pc-Living-Room/1207720P/).
>
> There are a few different theories, not [*mutually exclusively*](https://www.vox.com/2014/5/28/5758964/why-apple-is-buying-beats), as to what's driving Apple's interest in Beats.

And there are cases where the usage is not confused, but confusing:

> The two parties in marriage give themselves [*mutually exclusively*](http://www.aboutcatholics.com/beliefs/the-purpose-of-mass/) to each other and promise to make self-sacrifices to support the other person.

Now in the current state of the Roman Catholic Church, while for men marriage and the priesthood are mutually exclusive, marriage is both mutual *and* exclusive for both parties. The phrase *mutually exclusive* has stuck somewhere in the writer’s mind and overpowered the actual sense into a logical impossibility.

> Here we report that when rats were allowed to choose [*mutually-exclusively*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1931610/#!po=1.21951) between water sweetened with saccharin–an intense calorie-free sweetener–and intravenous cocaine–a highly addictive and harmful substance–the large majority of animals (94%) preferred the sweet taste of saccharin.

A choice is from the onset choosing one thing and not choosing another, so saying a choice is mutually exclusive is merely saying it’s a choice. Further, are the hapless rodents forced to choose between a saccharin solution and *intravenous* cocaine, and if so, how do they indicate a readiness for an injection? As it turns out, it’s a cocaine solution, and the rats are given two tries at levers delivering the one solution or the other:

> Importantly, each day before making their choices, rats were allowed to alternatively sample each lever 2 times to learn their respective reward value.

Only *after* the rats press a lever twice does anything resembling mutual exclusion occur, but after the levers are locked, there is no longer a choice.

#### Conclusion, at long last!

And that, in a rather roundabout way, brings us to your question. If you want people to download one and only one version of software, then tell them that:

> Download x or y, but not both.

If you use the adverb *mutually exclusively*, those who want the software have to figure out first what their choice must be to insure a state of mutual exclusion. Given the frequent misuse and misunderstanding of the adverb even in academic uses and its sheer infrequency, you are needlessly burdening anyone who wants your product.

Comment: apparently the OP got his question answered in comments.

Comment: @lbf: Well, it took some time to assemble all the citations and links so I posted the answer anyway. Besides, it was interesting to see all the adverbs used instead of the adjective. It didn’t occur to me that would even be possible.

Comment: good job ... answers are not supposed to be made in comments!